# How mov in x86 assembly language with nasm syntax works

Tags: assembly, x86

mov eax, 3

then what is encoding of eax ??, what will be stored in eax ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: The whole contents of the register will be replaced with 0x00000003 (only last two bits set, all the rest zero).

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "what is (the) encoding of eax"? X86 is little endian, two's complement, if that is what you meant. EAX is a 32 bit register. EAX will contain the value 3 in that format..

Comment: FWIW, NASM generally uses Intel syntax, which is most of the time ìn the form `opcode dest,source`.

Comment: @Thilo It means 3 is stored as a hexadecimal or decimal in EAX , if I need to add two numbers then what are the instructions should I add

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I am bit confused on how to store a integer in a register (say EAX ) and how to performs operations and if I output the result on console .. will it output as a decimal ..??

Comment: Putting numbers on the console is usually the result of a function or system call. How that is done depends on your system. A register like EAX can contain any 32 bit value. What this value actually means depends on you, i.e. on how you use it.

Answer (score 2):

Intel's insn ref manual (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has pseudocode and text (and diagrams where needed) for every instruction showing *exactly* happens to the machine state.